# How to tunnel whole device through a vpn from react native app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, vpn, android-vpn-service

I have been researching a way to create a VPN connection to tunnel whole device using react native but unfortunately there isn't any way to do that. There are Native Services to achieve that like `VPNService` in android and `NetworkExtension` in iOS but I've been unable to find a way or a library to do that in React Native. Is there any way to achieve that in react native or may be a method to expose device's VPN settings to manually set the configuration?